# How to assign uint8_t* into uint16_t in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

How to assign `uint8_t*` into `uint16_t`?

I have 3 functions:

- functionC: when it is id_A, it seperates data into two
- functionA: get size  for id_A
- functionB: get data for id_A based on size from functionA

However:

1) functionA uses `uint8_t*` , to return the size

2) FunctionB uses `uint16_t size` as input

3) I need to combine these to sizes as input of functionB in functionC

4) How to assign `uint8_t*` into `uint16_t`? Is it right way:  `(uint16_t)*outputSize` in [B]?

```
functionA(uint16_t id, uint8_t* size){
//return size based on id
}

functionB(uint16_t id, uint8_t* data, uint16_t dataSize){
//input:id, input: dataSize and return data 
}

functionC(id){
    uint8_t* outputSize;
    uint8_t* outData;

    fuctionA( id, outputSize);  //[A]outputSize is ouput here

    functionB( id, outData, (uint16_t)*outputSize)); //------[B] outputSize from [A] as input here
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Where is the `uint16_t` variable that you want to assign to? Do you want to store a `uint8_t *` into a `uint16_t`, or do you want to store a `uint8_t` _value_ (which may come from _dereferencing_ a pointer) into a `uint16_t`? The former doesn't make much sense, the latter is a matter of simple assignment.

Comment: What's the right way to convert a `char*` to a `char`? What's the right way to skin a cat? What's the right way to write a letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate memory somewhere. Get rid of the pointer and use a plain variable:

```
uint8_t outputSize;
```

Then call `fuctionA(id, &outputSize);`

And then simply pass on `outputSize` to the next function:

```
functionB( id, outData, outputSize);
```

or if you wish to be explicit:

```
functionB( id, outData, (uint16_t)outputSize);
```

Comment: Thanks. Guiding with a constructive tone. That's really encouraging the newbies.